# Symfony2.8 integration Payum Bundle

Tags: symfony, paypal, payum

I am using PayumBundle for paypal integration in my site.
I have setup the bundle, as described in 
https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/get_it_started.md

and installed paypal express checkout nvp extension for payum.

This is my controller:

```
            $gatewayName = 'paypal-express-checkout-nvp';

            $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage(PaymentDetails::class);

            $details = $storage->create();
            $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'CHF';
            $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $amount;
            $storage->update($details);

            $captureToken = $this->get('payum')->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
                $gatewayName, $details, 'payment_done'
            );

            return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
```

Here is config file:

```
payum:
  security:
    token_storage:
        MyBundle\Entity\PaymentToken: { doctrine: orm }

  storages:
    MyBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails: { doctrine: orm }

  gateways:
    paypal-express-checkout-nvp:
        factory: paypal_express_checkout
        username:  %paypal_user%
        password:  %paypal_password%
        signature: %paypal_signature%
        sandbox: true
```

However When i submit the form I'm getting following error"

```
 Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Api::__construct() must be an instance of Http\Message\MessageFactory, null given, called in vendor/payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/PaypalExpressCheckoutGatewayFactory.php on line 89 and defined in vendor/payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Api.php at 317
```

I had a look at PaypalExpressCheckoutGatewayFactory class where config is passed inside populateConfig function at line 89,

```
 return new Api($paypalConfig, $config['payum.http_client'], $config['httplug.message_factory']);
```

key 'httplug.message_factory' is not defined anywhere?

STACK TRACE:

```
 0 vendor/payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Api.php(317): Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 3 pass...', '...', 317, Array)
 1 vendor/payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/PaypalExpressCheckoutGatewayFactory.php(89): Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\Api->__construct(Array, Object(Payum\Core\Bridge\Guzzle\HttpClient), NULL)
 2 [internal function]: Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\PaypalExpressCheckoutGatewayFactory->Payum\Paypal\ExpressCheckout\Nvp\{closure}(Object(Payum\Core\Bridge\Spl\ArrayObject))
 3 vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/CoreGatewayFactory.php(123): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Payum\Core\Bridge\Spl\ArrayObject))
 4 vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Bridge/Symfony/ContainerAwareCoreGatewayFactory.php(35): Payum\Core\CoreGatewayFactory->buildClosures(Object(Payum\Core\Bridge\Spl\ArrayObject))
 5 vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/CoreGatewayFactory.php(40): Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\ContainerAwareCoreGatewayFactory->buildClosures(Object(Payum\Core\Bridge\Spl\ArrayObject))
 6 vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/GatewayFactory.php(33): Payum\Core\CoreGatewayFactory->create(Array)
 7 vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/PayumBuilder.php(422): Payum\Core\GatewayFactory->create(Array)
 8 app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(2209): Payum\Core\PayumBuilder->getPayum()
 9 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(316): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getPayumService()
 10 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php(391): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('payum')
 11 src/zenpme/BusinessBundle/Controller/PaymentController.php(74): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->get('payum')
 12 [internal function]: BusinessBundle\Controller\PaymentController->indexAction(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
 13 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(139): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
 14 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(62): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
 15 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php(69): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
 16 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(185): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
 17 web/app_dev.php(30): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
 18 {main}
```

Comment: can you add exception stack trace to question?

Comment: I have added stack trace. :)

Comment: Same problem with Symfony 3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `payum/core` at least `1.3` version.

- Change in Payum library: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/pull/505
- Change in Payum bundle: https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/pull/353/files
- Related github issue: https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/356

Comment: I installed httplug-bundle, guzzle-adapter. Enabled httplug classes in config.yml. Still having same error.

Comment: you are sure that you have `payum/core` in version >= 1.3?

Comment: Yes. Updated payum/core to 1.3.0

Comment: You need to have installed also `php-http/guzzle6-adapter`

Comment: Yes, I installed guzzle6-adapter, httplug-bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in Symfony3. 
To workaround add the array key => value:

```
httplug.message_factory' => new GuzzleMessageFactory()
```

in the PaypalExpressCheckoutGatewayFactory config-array.
I'll try to find a better solution and update the post later.

You also have to add this use statement:

```
use Http\Message\MessageFactory\GuzzleMessageFactory;
```

**EDIT**
I finally got it to work without changing the libraries but I actually don't know how. I installed the application on my server and did the php composer.phar install -o and it works.

This is my composer.json:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
        "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.0",
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3"
    },
```

Comment: i can not find GuzzleMessageFactory class anywhere. Do I have to install any library for it?   This is my current composer.json
"payum/payum-bundle": "^2.0",
"payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3",
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.0"

Comment: Well, I give up. I'm using Paypal's PHP APIs in my application. However I'm keeping this question open. If you find answer please post it, so that someone else can get solution if they are stuck in same error.

Comment: My Composer.json looks like this: "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.0",
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3" and nothing else (except standard symfony).